# Time out on Recordset with linked tables

Tags: vba

```
Dim rt As DAO.Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT A.OBJ FROM " 
strSQL = strSQL & "(SELECT VARBL AS OBJ FROM AGR_1252 WHERE AGR_NAME = '" _
    & AGR & "') A LEFT JOIN " 
strSQL = strSQL _
    & "(SELECT DISTINCT CONF_USOBT_C_ORG.ORG_OBJECT AS OBJ FROM Role_Content, CONF_USOBT_C_ORG " 
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE Role_Content.AGR_NAME = '" _
    & AGR & "' AND Role_Content.TCode = [CONF_USOBT_C_ORG].[Name] AND Role_Content.TCode <> '" & tc & "') B " 
strSQL = strSQL & "ON A.OBJ = B.OBJ WHERE B.OBJ Is Null"

Set rt = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

  Do While Not rt.EOF

      DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM AGR_1252 WHERE AGR_NAME = '" & AGR & "' AND VARBL = '" & rt("OBJ") & "'" ', False

rt.MoveNext

    Loop

rt.Close
Set rt = Nothing
```

I have the code above. I dont know why but it's giving me a time out error on the while loop. I dont know if it if because of the Recordset, but the table is blocking after he mades the firts Delete.

There is another way to select records without using RecordSet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the content of strSQL? You should be able to do this with a single sql statement to delete the records.

Comment: the content of strSQL is:                                           strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT A.OBJ FROM "
strSQL = strSQL & "(SELECT VARBL AS OBJ FROM AGR_1252 WHERE AGR_NAME = '" & AGR & "') A LEFT JOIN "
strSQL = strSQL & "(SELECT DISTINCT CONF_USOBT_C_ORG.ORG_OBJECT AS OBJ FROM Role_Content, CONF_USOBT_C_ORG "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE Role_Content.AGR_NAME =  '" & AGR & "' AND Role_Content.TCode = [CONF_USOBT_C_ORG].[Name] AND Role_Content.TCode <> '" & tc & "') B "
strSQL = strSQL & "ON A.OBJ = B.OBJ WHERE B.OBJ Is Null"

Comment: Does that query work for you? I notice that you are using two zero-length strings (`WHERE Role_Content.AGR_NAME = '"`). It is usually quite difficult to get a ZLS in Access, so I would expect `WHERE Role_Content.AGR_NAME Is Null"`

Comment: Yes, the query works fine.. i think that using OpenRecorset is blocking the table, so on the while loop he gives time out (he does the first delete, but when he does the second gives time out..)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something on the lines of:

```
DELETE FROM AGR_1252 
WHERE AGR_NAME = Agr
AND Varbl Not In (
  SELECT c.ORG_OBJECT 
  FROM Role_Content r 
  INNER JOIN CONF_USOBT_C_ORG c 
  ON r.TCode =c.[Name]
  WHERE r.AGR_NAME Is Null)
```

Comment: Thaks, but the query works fine because she delete the firts record, but when she try to delete the second record gives time out.. 
The query that you posted works the same way =|
I think that recordSet is blocking the table..There is another way to select data without using RecordSet?

Comment: The example I posted should run in the query design window. It does not delete one record at a time, but all records at once. It would clearly not be safe to test on real data.